Help identify movie where woman is dragged through street by motorbike
I remember seeing this scene, where the woman's handbag is grabbed by a guy on a motorbike but the bag is attached via a chain or something to her wrist.
She is then dragged through the street.
I think the movie was late 70s or early 80s and possibly Italian or American but these are just cloudy memories.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Sorry but I don't think I saw the whole movie, which is why I'm trying to find out what it was. I'm searching my memory but this is about all I can remember.

I found it!
Live like a cop, die like a man (1976)
Now that I discover who directed it (Ruggero Deodato), I'm not surprised it stood out in my memory. He later went on to make Cannibal Holocaust and House on the Edge of the Park, which are both on the DPP 39 "Video Nasty" list.
The scene I referred to in the question is quite brutal and actually opens the movie, which also explains why it's the only that bit I can remember.
